# Input all row values of dataframe into a variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqldf

is there a way to get all output values of rows in dataframe into a variable?

my code is like this..

```
q1 = ps.sqldf("SELECT sdetframe.bill_no AS 'bill_number', sdetframe.ref_no AS 'ref_number', sdetframe.price_paid AS 'price_paid', sdetframe.raw_price AS 'raw_price', sdetframe.quanty AS 'quantity' FROM sdetframe WHERE ord_date = '" + dfd + "'")
q1df = DataFrame(q1)
q1data = q1df.at[0, 'bill_number']
print(q1df)
```

the output of q1df is this...

```
        bill_number  ref_number  price_paid  raw_price  quantity
0          197968           2      383.93     383.93       1.0
1          197968           2      383.93     383.93       1.0
2          197968           2      383.93     383.93       1.0
3          197969           1      357.14     357.14       1.0
4          197969         151      500.00     500.00       1.0
```

and the output of q1data is only 197968. is there a way where i can get all the bill number values and put it into a variable??

thanks in advance.

i put it into a variable so i can call it to another dataframe query. below is another code...

```
q2 = ps.sqldf("SELECT slsframe.pay_type AS 'pay_type', slsframe.received AS 'received' FROM slsframe WHERE bill_no = '" + str(q1data) + "'")
q2df = DataFrame(q2)
```

Comment: `pandas` `at` method only returns one value

Comment: i see. i use the tolist() function now.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be put all the values as a list using `tolist()`.

`q1data= q1df.bill_number.tolist()`

Prints:

`[197968, 197968, 197968, 197969, 197969]`

***EDIT***
User wants to use it for another SQL query as per question update.

For that, convert the `list` to `tuple` and call the query.

```
q1data = tuple(q1data)
ps.sqldf("SELECT slsframe.pay_type AS 'pay_type', slsframe.received AS 'received' FROM slsframe WHERE bill_no IN %(q1data)")
```

If you want duplicates removed from list then convert into `set` and then into `tuple`.

Comment: thanks a lot. but the reason i want to put the bill_number values is i will use it to another query. i will edit the code again for you to see.

Comment: Another Pandas query or SQL query?

Comment: another sql query.

Comment: You can use `.isin` to query as a list from another dataframe

Comment: I have updated the answer to include that requirement

Comment: pandasql.sqldf.PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "%": syntax error
[SQL: SELECT slsframe.pay_type AS 'pay_type', slsframe.received AS 'received' FROM slsframe WHERE bill_no IN %(q1data)]

Comment: above comment is the error im getting.

Comment: ok.. can u try `q2 = ps.sqldf("SELECT slsframe.pay_type AS 'pay_type', slsframe.received AS 'received' FROM slsframe WHERE bill_no = '" + ','.join(map(str, q1data)) + "'")`

Comment: still getting the same error.

Comment: It might be difficult to trouble shoot sql queries. I think you get the idea, convert the bill number into a tuple and pass it to the query using "IN" statement in SQL.

Comment: im not really familiar using query in dataframe so i use the sql query. btw thanks a lot

Comment: i try using q1data[0] and it only get the first row. how can i use all row.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the variable to be a `Series`:

```
S1 = q1df['bill_number']
```

Output:

```
0    197968
1    197968
2    197968
3    197969
4    197969
```

If you want the variable to be a `List`:

```
L1 = q1df['bill_number'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['197968', '197968', '197968', '197969', '197969']
```

Comment: i want to put the bill_number values to a variable so i can use it to another sql query. i edit the question above. thanks.